# webform and captcha module in drupal

Tags: drupal, webforms, module, captcha, spam

Has anyone had any problems with the captcha module in combination with the webform module? I am not sure if it's something that I can use for work if spam bots can overpass the captcha... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the use of the Mollom module:

http://drupal.org/project/mollom

It's spam protection is much better than that of Captcha:

http://drupal.org/project/captcha

Once setup, Mollom spam protection can be added to Webforms.